# Start-Process does not parse argumentlist

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have created a PowerShell script, but for some reason the "Start-Process"-cmdlet does not seem to be behaving correctly.  Here is my code:

```
[string]$ListOfProjectFiles = "project_file*."
[string]$arg   = "project_file"
[string]$log   = "C:\Work\output.log"
[string]$error = "C:\Work\error.log"

Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -filter $ListOfProjectFiles | `
    ForEach-Object {
        [string]$OldFileName = $_.Name
        [string]$Identifier = ($_.Name).Substring(($_.Name).LastIndexOf("_") + 1)

        Rename-Item $PSScriptRoot\$_ -NewName "project_file"

        Start-Process "$PSScriptRoot\MyExecutable.exe" ` #This line causes my headaches.
                        -ArgumentList $arg `
                        -RedirectStandardError $error `
                        -RedirectStandardOutput $log `
                        -Wait
        Remove-Item "C:\Work\output.log", "C:\Work\error.log"

        Rename-Item "$PSScriptRoot\project_file" -NewName $OldFileName
        }
```

The main issue is, is that on my machine the program runs, but only after I added the `-Wait` switch.  I found out that if I stepped through my code in the PowerShell-ISE, `MyExecutable.exe` **did** recognise the argument and ran the program properly, while if I just ran the script without breakpoints, it would error as if it could not parse the `$arg` value.  Adding the `-Wait` switch seemed to solve the problem on my machine.

On the machine of my colleague, `MyExecutable.exe` does not recognise the output of the `-ArgumentList $arg` part: it just quits with an error stating that the required argument (which should be `"project_file"`) could not be found.

I have tried to hard-code the `"project_file"` part, but that is no success.  I have also been playing around with the other switches for the `Start-Process`-cmdlet, but nothing works.  I am a bit at a loss, quite new to PowerShell, but totally confused why it behaves differently on different computers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try passing `project_file` with the full path?

Comment: Try dropping the newlines from the `Start-Process` call, it's possible that they get transferred to cmdline parser and cause it to malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

If you does not use `-Wait` switch, then your script continue to run while `MyExecutable.exe` still executing. In particular you can rename file back (`Rename-Item "$PSScriptRoot\project_file" -NewName $OldFileName`) before you program open it.

You pass plain `project_file` as argument to your program. What if current working directory is not a `$PSScriptRoot`? Does `MyExecutable.exe` designed to look for files in the exe location directory in addition to/instead of current working directory? I recommend to supply full path instead:

```
[string]$arg   = "`"$PSScriptRoot\project_file`""
```

Do not just convert `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` objects to string. It does not guaranteed to return full path or just file name. Explicitly ask for `Name` or `FullName` property value, depending of what you want.

```
Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "project_file"
```